# Regresar el valor incial de no mostrar contraseña con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando que un Input muestre y oculte contraseña con JavaScript, y al mismo tiempo que se abra y cierre el ojo. El problema que tengo es que una vez que muestro la contraseña, no puedo regresar a que no se vuelva a mostrar al seleccionar que la oculte (Ojo cerrado o fa-eye-slash).

¿Cuál podría ser el problema?

Comparto el código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navbutton').click(function () {
        var control = $(this);
        var estatus = control.data('activo');
        $(this).find('.fa-eye,.fa-eye-slash').toggleClass('fa-eye  ').toggleClass('fa-light fa-eye-slash');
        if (estatus == true) {
            $("#password").attr('type', 'password');                
        }
        else {
            $("#password").attr('type', 'text');              
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4d529f15e3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Escribe tu contraseña"  />
<p class="navbutton" data-activo="false" >
    <i class="fa fa-light fa-eye fa-2x " >
    </i> 
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Te comparto el siguiente ciclo de cambio (true -false) con un switch y la variable "estatus" la debes ocupar como un string ya que así la definiste en el data-activo

```
    $('.navbutton').click(function () {
        var control = $(this);
        var estatus = $(this).attr("data-activo");


        //ciclo de cambio activo al haber algún valor ingresado
        if($("#password").val() != ""){

        switch (estatus) {
            case "true":
            $(this).attr("data-activo",false);
            console.log(estatus)
                break;

            case "false":
            $(this).attr("data-activo",true);
            console.log(estatus)
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        $(this).find('.fa-eye,.fa-eye-slash').toggleClass('fa-eye  ').toggleClass('fa-light fa-eye-slash');
        //tipo string
        if (estatus == "true") {
            $("#password").attr('type', 'password');
        }
        else {
            $("#password").attr('type', 'text');
        }

    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Siempre es importante saber cual es el valor de tus variables.

---

Hagamos un `console.log()` a tu variable `estatus` para ver qué valor tiene cada vez que hagamos clic a tu ícono:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.navbutton').click(function () {
    var control = $(this);
    var estatus = control.data('activo');
    console.log(estatus);
    $(this).find('.fa-eye,.fa-eye-slash').toggleClass('fa-eye  ').toggleClass('fa-light fa-eye-slash');
    if (estatus == true) {
      $("#password").attr('type', 'password');
    }
    else {
      $("#password").attr('type', 'text');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4d529f15e3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Escribe tu contraseña"  />
<p class="navbutton" data-activo="false">
  <i class="fa fa-light fa-eye fa-2x "></i> 
</p>
```

Si te das cuenta, el valor de tu variable siempre es `false`, por la cual siempre está ingresando al `else`, cambiando el atributo de tu input a texto, o sea, esto se debe a que el valor de tu variable **nunca cambia**.

---

Entonces, se me ocurre cambiar el valor de la variable cada vez que le hagamos clic al ícono, así indicamos que el valor va a actualizarse cada vez que se ingrese al evento. Entonces, podemos agregar esto al final del evento para que el valor se actualice cada vez que entre a tu evento:

```js
control.data('activo', !estatus);
```

Para que se entienda mejor qué hace esto, te doy un ejemplo: Mira que al principio, tu valor es `false` y entra al `else`, luego **cambio** ese valor a `true`, diciendo que la siguiente vez que ingrese al evento será `true` (porque lo cambié a `true` antes) y así entra al `if`, y luego ese `true` se cambia a `false`, e indico que en la siguiente será `false` y así entra al `else`, sucesivamente (espero me logre entender).

Código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.navbutton').click(function () {
    var control = $(this);
    var estatus = control.data('activo');
    console.log(estatus);
    $(this).find('.fa-eye,.fa-eye-slash').toggleClass('fa-eye  ').toggleClass('fa-light fa-eye-slash');
    if (estatus == true) {
      $("#password").attr('type', 'password');
    }
    else {
      $("#password").attr('type', 'text');
    }
    control.data('activo', !estatus);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4d529f15e3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Escribe tu contraseña"  />
<p class="navbutton" data-activo="false">
  <i class="fa fa-light fa-eye fa-2x "></i> 
</p>
```